# How to generate a random name with a preceding nametag in Screeps?

Tags: javascript, screeps

In the Programming Game Screeps I spawn creeps by using:

```
if(transporters.length < 0 && harvesters.length > 2) {
var newName = Game.spawns['SpawnZone'].createCreep([WORK,CARRY,MOVE], undefined, {role: 'transporter'});
console.log('Spawning new Transporter: ' + newName);
}
```

The 'undefined' tag is to spawn the creep with a random name. Now I'm wondering since I got different types of creeps if I can add a roletag infront of it? Like, for example, [Transporter] RandomName.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could implement a function that will generate the name in the format you want and replace undefined with the generated name

Comment: thats possible? i wasnt sure if i can change the undefined value

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I will elaborate further in the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement a function that will generate the name in the format you want and replace `undefined` with the generated name. From Screeps [documentation](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/205990342-StructureSpawn#createCreep):

> **createCreep(body, [name], [memory])**
>
> Start the creep spawning process. The required energy amount can be
>   withdrawn from all spawns and extensions in the room.
>
> [...]
>
> **name (optional) string**
>
> The name of a new creep. It should be unique
>   creep name, i.e. the Game.creeps object should not contain another
>   creep with the same name (hash key). If not defined, a random name
>   will be generated.

The Screeps Forum actually already has a [solution](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208283649-Please-give-us-access-to-random-name-generator-for-creeps) for what you need. Transcript below:

```
var names1 = ["Jackson", "Aiden", "Liam", "Lucas", "Noah", "Mason", "Jayden", "Ethan", "Jacob", "Jack", "Caden", "Logan", "Benjamin", "Michael", "Caleb", "Ryan", "Alexander", "Elijah", "James", "William", "Oliver", "Connor", "Matthew", "Daniel", "Luke", "Brayden", "Jayce", "Henry", "Carter", "Dylan", "Gabriel", "Joshua", "Nicholas", "Isaac", "Owen", "Nathan", "Grayson", "Eli", "Landon", "Andrew", "Max", "Samuel", "Gavin", "Wyatt", "Christian", "Hunter", "Cameron", "Evan", "Charlie", "David", "Sebastian", "Joseph", "Dominic", "Anthony", "Colton", "John", "Tyler", "Zachary", "Thomas", "Julian", "Levi", "Adam", "Isaiah", "Alex", "Aaron", "Parker", "Cooper", "Miles", "Chase", "Muhammad", "Christopher", "Blake", "Austin", "Jordan", "Leo", "Jonathan", "Adrian", "Colin", "Hudson", "Ian", "Xavier", "Camden", "Tristan", "Carson", "Jason", "Nolan", "Riley", "Lincoln", "Brody", "Bentley", "Nathaniel", "Josiah", "Declan", "Jake", "Asher", "Jeremiah", "Cole", "Mateo", "Micah", "Elliot"]
var names2 = ["Sophia", "Emma", "Olivia", "Isabella", "Mia", "Ava", "Lily", "Zoe", "Emily", "Chloe", "Layla", "Madison", "Madelyn", "Abigail", "Aubrey", "Charlotte", "Amelia", "Ella", "Kaylee", "Avery", "Aaliyah", "Hailey", "Hannah", "Addison", "Riley", "Harper", "Aria", "Arianna", "Mackenzie", "Lila", "Evelyn", "Adalyn", "Grace", "Brooklyn", "Ellie", "Anna", "Kaitlyn", "Isabelle", "Sophie", "Scarlett", "Natalie", "Leah", "Sarah", "Nora", "Mila", "Elizabeth", "Lillian", "Kylie", "Audrey", "Lucy", "Maya", "Annabelle", "Makayla", "Gabriella", "Elena", "Victoria", "Claire", "Savannah", "Peyton", "Maria", "Alaina", "Kennedy", "Stella", "Liliana", "Allison", "Samantha", "Keira", "Alyssa", "Reagan", "Molly", "Alexandra", "Violet", "Charlie", "Julia", "Sadie", "Ruby", "Eva", "Alice", "Eliana", "Taylor", "Callie", "Penelope", "Camilla", "Bailey", "Kaelyn", "Alexis", "Kayla", "Katherine", "Sydney", "Lauren", "Jasmine", "London", "Bella", "Adeline", "Caroline", "Vivian", "Juliana", "Gianna", "Skyler", "Jordyn"]

Creep.getRandomName = function(prefix){
    var name, isNameTaken, tries = 0;
    do {
        var nameArray = Math.random() > .5 ? names1 : names2;
        name = nameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameArray.length)];

        if (tries > 3){
            name += nameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameArray.length)];
        }

        tries++;
        isNameTaken = Game.creeps[name] !== undefined;
    } while (isNameTaken);

    return prefix+" "+name;
}
```

Comment: i tried [Builder]+creep.random.name  but then i get the error Builder is not defined so i think tit doesnt work as planned. kinda clueless how to do my own function x)

Comment: If you want completely random names, you can try the solution described on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/1814415

Comment: Not really. id like to have a prefix that display the roles of my creeps ^,^

Comment: You can pass the prefix as a parameter to the function and concatenate it before returning

Comment: actually i wouldnt mind having the tag behind the names.  is there a way to still use the random function (undefined) and just add it behind? i think i did a formatting mistake.. thought it would work like  undefined +'[Role]' :/

Comment: If you do undefined +'[Role]', that becomes the string "undefined[Role]", which is not what you want. The correct way to implement this is using a function for the name generation.

Comment: Hmm guess i have a problem then. i dont know how to write my own function or even call it from another file x)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124726/discussion-between-user3220962-and-azev).

Answer (score 10):

I found that just naming with their job and the current game time fills the need well.

ex: `"Builder" + Game.time.toString()` = Builder1234

A spawn can only make one creep at a time, so the name should always be unique.

Only issue is if 2+ spawners try to make a bot at the same time *(same tick)*, whomever didn't start the spawn first will fail with with `ERR_NAME_EXISTS`, but you could just get them on your next cycle.

[image]

Comment: I like this idea. I'd improve it with canCreateCreep. Then add digits of game time until there is no conflict. That way the names stay as short as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Matthew-Regul I just gave them a random serial number attached to their duty :

```
'UPGRADER_' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 65534) + 1)
```

Although his removes the extremely slight possibility of repeated names

Answer (score 0):

I found that the default naming scheme in screeps is lacking because the name doesn't say much about the role of creeps. For this I wrote a small utility class called util.nameBuilder.

It uses `Memory.nameIndex = {};` to keep track of the number of times a prefix has been assigned to a creep. Because I don't want to randomly increase the count if the spawning of a creep failed I have a `getName(role)` and a `commitName(role)`. `getName()` returns a name for use and `commitName()` will increase the count by 1. You might want to 'fold' the count if it goes above a certain threshold(say 1000) to prevent names like harvester243874. My spawn method will actually call `commitName(role)` if `createCreep()` returns a 'name already in use' error.

The result of this code are names like:
harvester1, builder23, upgrader5

```
var nameBuilder = {
    getName: function(role) {
        if (Memory.nameIndex === undefined)
            Memory.nameIndex = {};

        if (Memory.nameIndex[role] === undefined) 
            Memory.nameIndex[role] = 0;

        return role + (Memory.nameIndex[role] + 1);
    },

    commitName: function(role) {
        var newIndex = Memory.nameIndex[role] + 1;
        Memory.nameIndex[role] = newIndex;
    }
};

module.exports = nameBuilder;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Upgrader_" + spawn.name + "_" + Game.time
```

Creates a garanteed unique name.